# get css in the folders using assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

I would like to know if it is possible with symfony 2 and Assetics to say that I want to load all of the css files in a specific folder even though this one has some other folders inside.

For example I have :

```
css/aaa.css

css/bbb.css

css/jquery/ccc.css

css/jquery/ddd.css
```

in assetics I would do that to load :

```
{% stylesheets  'bundles/my-bundle/css/*' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

this will only load aaa.css and bbb.css

Is there a way to say : 'take everything' in one single line (sure i could add each folder in the stylesheets tag but I want to know if I can avoid doing that)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this thing directly with assetic as is yet but it's possible thanks to everzet and his AsseticPipeline class suite and will probably be brought in next Assetic major version.

So what to do now ?

- test previous KnpRadBundle version by [cloning it here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/tree/v1.0)
- get more information about how to implement it in your project : [read this discussion](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/issues/71?source=c)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the app_dev environment, the files are processed for each request, and run through all the filters before they are provided by the Assetic controller. This is useful, because we will see every change directly:

[image]

In a production environment, this process is just too slow. In this case, Assetic is able to generate real files, which are static and can be delivered statically:

[image]

To generate the final assets, invoke the following script in your console:

```
      $ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

All the css will combine in the production environment.The above command will generate a css folder and a combined file into that folder.